# Why not number some definitions in Rudin's book?

Tags: education

I'm reading Rudin's Principle of Math Analysis

Why some definitions about functions in Chapter 8, there are no the number marks, and the boldfaced words `Definition`?

This chapter only have 22 marked theorem and definitions and...

For example

## Section 3

---

We define

$$\begin{align*}E(z)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{z^n}{n!}\quad \quad\tag{1}\end{align*}$$

## Section 4

---

Let us define

$$\begin{align*}C(x)=\frac{1}{2}[E(\text{ix})+E(-\text{ix})]\tag{2}\end{align*}$$

Is there some reason's in doing these things? i.e. Boldface and number some theorems/definitions in one book.

Comment: I suggest you ask Rudin (is he still with us?). Sorry, he passed away in 2010. I guess we'll never know.

Comment: @GerryMyerson fine...Maybe this is one general question? Other's books have some similar situations?

Comment: Maybe it's more a notation than really the definition of a concept.

Comment: I'm not sure what the **exact** question is, but there's a number besides each definition/formula. That seems to be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are purely local definitions, used only temporarily. The whole point of those sections is to prove that this function $E(z)$ is just the exponential function $e^z$, that this $C(x)$ is just $\cos x$, and that the similarly defined $S(x)$ is just $\sin x$.